# show content based on angular drop down array of objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, html-select

I haven't been able to find and example of using angular drop downs using an array of objects in the drop down menu, can someone please help me debug this? I eventually want the "Show me" to be a radio button list from the angular library.

```
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        Method:
        <select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="x.name for x in names">
        </select>
    </div>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
            $scope.names = [{name: 'Experiment'}, {name: 'Clinical Trial'}, {name: 'Case Report'}];
              $scope.changeme = function() {
                alert('here');
              }
        });
    </script>
    <div ng-if = "x.name == 'Experiment'">
        <span>Show Me</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Sorry, not following this exactly -- Where would the dropdown menu go? You talk about the dropdown, but then say you want a radio group. Can you clarify? Ultimately, I think you're going to want to take a look at the ng-repeat tag, but your answer to the above question will help us debug it for you: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: Hi there, so I want to have a drop down menu that once you select an option, a series of radio buttons appears as a form specific to that selection from the drop down menu

Answer (score 0):

Working version

```
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    Method:
    <select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="name.name as 
        name.name for name in names">
    </select>

<div ng-if = "selectedName === 'Experiment'">
    <span>Show Me</span>
</div>
      </div>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.selectedName = null;
        $scope.names = [{name: 'Experiment'}, {name: 'Clinical Trial'}, {name: 'Case Report'}];

    });
</script>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yRuk1yrENiU7WbmDyh1s?p=preview)

Your problem is that you put your "Show me" block outside ng-app